# Unhandled promise rejection with bcrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, bcrypt

I'm working on an Angular project. But I got the following error message when I'm trying to update a user's email and password with bcrypt. I attached my code.

"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPZkD.png)

Comment: if you are using the .compare ,all you need to do is just add a .catch block.

Comment: So you are hashing the email as well ? Usually this happens if your post request has some issues or something wrong in the middle ware logic. Could you show your code !! It’s hard to tell what you are doing wrong, at least the part you are calling the bcrypt